# Pandas Dataframe: Update dataframe value where condition matches multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where multiple rows have the same Symbol. I want all of these rows to be updated to the same SecurityID, populated from a different dataframe. Currently the best output I've gotten only updates the first occurrence of the Symbol.
DF1:

```
       Symbol  SecurityID
3856     UGE         NaN
13583    UGE         NaN  
25422    UGE         NaN 
36046    UGE         NaN 
47362    UGE         NaN  
58434    UGE         NaN
```

DF2:

```
      Symbol  SecurityID
3856    UGE    128901
```

I tried `merge`, `update`, and `concat`. Best output was from `df1.update(df2)`. Trying to do this without looping.
Output:

```
       Symbol  SecurityID
3856     UGE         128901
13583    UGE         NaN  
25422    UGE         NaN 
36046    UGE         NaN 
47362    UGE         NaN  
58434    UGE         NaN
```

Comment: What's the problem with `df1.update(df2)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.update()` seems to be the right tool for the job, but it works on the index. You can use [`.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to set that up, after converting `df2` into a mapping:

```
df1['SecurityID'].update(df1['Symbol'].map(df2.set_index('Symbol')['SecurityID']))
```

Result:

```
      Symbol SecurityID
3856     UGE     128901
13583    UGE     128901
25422    UGE     128901
36046    UGE     128901
47362    UGE     128901
58434    UGE     128901
```

Answer (score 0):

as another variant you can fill NaNs

```
df1['SecurityID'].fillna('128901', inplace=True)
```